# Get text from div, add some more text, save as variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's what I've got:

```
<div id="fivearea">Something</div>
```

Then later:

```
var 5popup= $('#fivearea').text();
```

This makes `5popup` = "Something".

However, I want to add some more text to what's in the div and save that as a variable. Psuedo-code:

```
var 5popup= $('#fivearea').text()+"some additional text";
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Your pseudocode is fine as is. Just use that. Except that variable names can't begin with a number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to add to the current value of the variable like this:

```
    5popup += "some additional text";
```

Answer (score 1):

Replacing the text inside the node below:

```
<div id="testId">hello</div>
```

Can be accomplished as follows

```
$("#testId").html("good bye");
```

Resulting in the html:

```
<div id="testId">good bye</div>
```

Similarly the text inside the node can be saved to a variable as follows:

```
var myTest = $("#testId").html();
```

If you want to add to the text inside a node without deleting anything, this can be accomplished with the append function. Given the following html.

```
<div id="testId">hello</div>
```

The code:

```
$("#testId").append(" world");
```

Will result in the html:

```
<div id="testId">hello world</div>
```

Comment: I read the question as asking how to get a variable whose value is the text from some div, plus some extra text. I don't see where in the question he is asking how to change the text in the div.

Comment: He didn't accept my answer so I expect your right. However I interpret "I want to add some more text to what's in the div" as needing to append to the DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
var text = $('#fivearea').text();
text += "Your text here";
$('#fivearea').text(text);
```

If you want to access the text, use the variable `text`. Hope this helped.